# SQL server calculate total of minutes per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculated the time of an intervention per day:
Imagine the following scenario:

| Intervention Start | Intervention End | Total time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2021 10:00:00 | 01/09/2021 12:00:00 | 01/09/2021 02:00:00 |
| 02/09/2021 23:30:00 | 03/09/2021 01:30:00 | 02/09/2021 00:30:00 and 03/09/2021 01:30:00 |

What is the best way to achieve this?

We can have more than 1 day of difference between interventions, also.

Comment: Outer join your table with a calendar table.

Comment: @Serg how exactly I can do that?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a difference as milliseconds, seconds, minutes ... depending on your precision requirements. ie:

```
select interventionStart, interventionEnd, datediff(seconds, interventionStart, interventionEnd) totalTime
from myTable;
```

You could then convert seconds to your desire of display (ie: in .Net you might use TimeSpan's ToString() method.)

EDIT: If you absolutely need times "per date", then you could do this:

```
WITH
  adjusted AS (
                SELECT
                      interventionStart, interventionEnd
                FROM  myTable
                WHERE CAST(interventionStart AS DATE)=CAST(interventionEnd AS DATE)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                      interventionStart, CAST(interventionEnd AS DATE) interventionEnd
                FROM  myTable
                WHERE CAST(interventionStart AS DATE)!=CAST(interventionEnd AS DATE)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                      CAST(interventionEnd AS DATE) interventionStart, interventionEnd
                FROM  myTable
                WHERE CAST(interventionStart AS DATE)!=CAST(interventionEnd AS DATE)
              )
SELECT
     adjusted.interventionStart
   , adjusted.interventionEnd
   , DATEDIFF(SECOND, interventionStart, interventionEnd) totalTime
   , DATEADD(
              SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, interventionStart, interventionEnd)
            , CAST(CAST(adjusted.interventionStart AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
            )                                             ifYouWish
FROM adjusted;
```

[DbFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=734aa49b9f011f30ffbc30b7b63026f6)

Comment: Yes @CetinBasoz, thank you that covers part of what I want. But what's the best way to give exactly the time per day when I have interventions that "touches" to days like the second line on my example.

Comment: @Mendes, it doesn't matter, still in seconds the difference is fixed (7200 = 2 * 60 * 60).

Comment: @Mendes, Oh you mean you want to get times per date? Then it would need the data to be grouped per date. I will add an edit for that.

Comment: @Mendes, edited. ifYouWish column is just there as a conversion to a datetime presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if it answers your question.

```
SELECT Intervention_Start, Intervention_End, AGE(Intervention_Start, 
Intervention_End) AS Total_Time from <table_name>;
```

Comment: Hi @Ann Francis, thank you yap it covers part of what I need. And how can I do the second line?

Comment: @Mendes Now I see what you want. Will look into that.

Comment: Thank you @Ann Francis, I'll appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Time in seconds by date. You can covert it to minutes, hours at will

```
select cast(c.d as date) dt, datediff(second, case when c.d > m.InterventionStart then c.d else m.InterventionStart end,
                             case when c2.d < m.InterventionEnd then c2.d else m.InterventionEnd end) seconds
from calendar c -- contains d = datetime of the start of the day, 2021-09-01 00:00:00 etc
-- next day
cross apply (values (dateadd(day, 1, c.d))) c2(d)
left join mytable m on c.d < m.InterventionEnd and m.InterventionStart < c2.d
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6ba50d5ed6c69069add0e5df6df2d777)